# how to dynamically resize input tag

Tags: html, input, css

I have a dynamic link displayed inside an input tag. How can I make the input tag resize to take the width of the link?

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a body onload to determine the size....

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Example</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
thelink = document.getElementById('MyLink');
linksize = thelink.value.length;
if (linksize < 10) thelink.size = 10;
if (linksize > 50) thelink.size = 50;
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<input id="MyLink" type="text" value="http://www.domain.com/this/is/a/very/long/link/example" />
</body>

</html>
```

jus tset your minimum and maximum size for maintaining page style....

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can create a hidden `<span>` identically styled, then read its width (because it adjusts to its contents) and assign the width to the `<input>`.